# VMware vCenter API exception:The request refers to an unexpected or unknown type?

Tags: java, vmware, vcenter

The console shows exception:"The request refers to an unexpected or unknown type" when I create a cluster.please help me. code shows the following:

```
 vimPort.login(serviceContent.getSessionManager(),
                userName, password, null);
 ManagedObjectReference data = getDatacenterByName2("Datacenter");
 String name = "cluster_hi";
 ClusterConfigSpec spec = new ClusterConfigSpec(); 
 ClusterDasConfigInfo value = new ClusterDasConfigInfo(); 
 value.setAdmissionControlEnabled(true); 
 value.setEnabled(true);
 spec.setDasConfig(value); 
 vimPort.createCluster(data, name, spec);
```

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: 
The request refers to an unexpected or unknown type.

```
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:119)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)

at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.createCluster(Unknown Source)

at com.huawei.robo.common.vcenterclient.VcenterClientImpl.main(VcenterClientImpl.java:162)
```

Comment: Please add the exceptions stacktrace to your question

Comment: The exceptions already added.Thank you!